# Calling functions using the RPC Interface in OpenFlipper

Tags: c++, plugins, rpc

I'm writing a plugin for OpenFlipper that programatically add primitive shapes. A prexisting plugin, PrimativesGenerator,  has some of the same functionality that I will need, so naturally, I'd prefer to call the functions of PrimativesGeneratorPlugin rather than reproduce the code.

PrimativesGenerator implements the RPC Interface for calling functions of other plugins. Based on the documentation, I have tried using the RPCWrapper.hh to call the addSphere function with the code below

This code successfully loads a plugin. And when I throw in a breakpoint, it appears to call the RPC::callFunction without exceptions or other bad behavior. However, it doesn't seem to make a sphere. What am I missing about the interface here?

My previous question ([Is it possible to call another plugin's function from another plugin in OpenFlipper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910309/is-it-possible-to-call-another-plugins-function-from-another-plugin-in-openflip/23995950#23995950)) addressed the general problem of how to call the function. With this question, I am hoping to understand the specifics of the RPC interface better.

MakeSphere.h

```
#include <QObject>
#include <OpenFlipper/BasePlugin/BaseInterface.hh>
#include <OpenFlipper/BasePlugin/ToolboxInterface.hh>

#include <OpenFlipper/BasePlugin/RPCWrappers.hh>
#include <OpenFlipper/common/Types.hh>

class MakeSphere : public QObject, BaseInterface, ToolboxInterface
{
    Q_OBJECT 
    Q_INTERFACES(BaseInterface)
Q_INTERFACES(ToolboxInterface)

signals:
    //BaseInterface
    void updateView();
    void updatedObject(int _identifier, const UpdateType& _type);
    // ToolboxInterface
    void addToolbox( QString _name, QWidget* _widget );

public:
    // Base Interface
    QString name()         { return QString("Make Sphere"); }
    QString description( ) { return QString( tr("Makes a sphere") ); }

private slots:
    // BaseInterface
    void initializePlugin();
    void pluginsInitialized();
};
```

MakeSphere.c

```
#include "MakeSphere.h"

#include <OpenFlipper/BasePlugin/PluginFunctions.hh>

void MakeSphere::initializePlugin()
{
QWidget *toolBox = new QWidget();
emit addToolbox(tr("Make Sphere"), toolBox);
}    

void MakeSphere::pluginsInitialized()
{
Vector *Cvec = new Vector(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
RPC::callFunction ("PrimativesGeneratorPlugin", "addSphere", *Cvec, 1.0);
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2( makeSphere, MakeSphere );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RPC::callFunction function does not appear to throw exceptions or errors if the given plugin or function names are incorrect.

In this case, the correct call is

```
RPC::callFunction ("primitivesgenerator", "addSphere", *Cvec, 1.0);
```

Or if the return value is desired

```
int val = RPC::callFunctionValue<int>("primitivesgenerator", "addSphere", *Cvec, 1.0);
```

The plugin name does not nessisarily match the class name or even the plugin export statement name. To find the correct plugin name, I used the 'Scripting' menu in OpenFlipper.